# Sending an email using FuelSDK-Node-SOAP

Tags: email, fuel-sdk, node.js

I'm lost in the woods... We're creating a node application that needs to use the SOAP api to `TriggeredSend` one-off transactional emails using FuelSDK-Node-SOAP. Looking for a code example.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using the api and I keep getting slapped for my customerKey

```
  var soapOptions = {
    CustomerKey: 'FROM-EXTERNAL_KEY-IN-DATA-EXTENSION',
    Subscribers: {
      EmailAddress: 'fake@email.com',
      Lists: {ID: '12345'},
      SubscriberKey: '1235-42434-43434-434434'
    },
    TriggeredSendDefinition: {
      CustomerKey: 'EXTERNAL_KEY_FROM_TRIGGERED_SEND',
      Email: {
        CustomerKey: 'EMAIL_ID'
      }
    },
    ClientID: { ID:BUSINESS_UNIT_INT },
  };

 SoapClient.create(
      'TriggeredSend',
      soapOptions,
      {},
      function (err, response) {})
```

Is what I have and may help, although I'm not sure where to get the proper customer keys for the respective items...

Answer (score 0):

I was am doing this with fuel-rest and it works well.

src/controllers/mcloud.utils.js

```
var FuelRest = require('fuel-rest');
var BPromise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function(app) {

  var mcloudTools = {};
  mcloudTools.messageDefinitionSends = function(options) {

    var sendKey = "8123631-87a4-428b-80dc123a4bc0a1"; // Trigger email
    var fromAddress = "code@exacttarget.com";

    var options = {
        uri: '/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/' + 'key:' + sendKey + '/send',

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: {
            "From": {
                "Address": fromAddress,
                "Name": "Sender"
            },
            "To": {
                "Address": 'first.last@company.com'
                , "SubscriberKey": "SDKSubscriberDS"
                , "ContactAttributes": {
                    "SubscriberAttributes": {
                        "ConversionReferenceId": req.attributes.uuid_card_url
                    }
                }
            }
            , "OPTIONS": {
                "RequestType": "ASYNC"
            }
        }
    };

    return new BPromise(function(fulfill, reject) {

        var restOptions  = {
            auth: {
                clientId: process.env.MCLOUD_CLIENTID
                , clientSecret: process.env.MCLOUD_SECRET
            }
            // , origin: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com' // default --> https://www.exacttargetapis.com
        };
        var RestClient = new FuelRest(restOptions);
        return RestClient
            .post(options)
            .then(function(response) {
                fulfill(response);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });

    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a triggered send, I had success with:

```
var BPromise = require('bluebird');
var ET_Client = require( 'fuelsdk-node' );
var clientId = process.env.MCLOUD_CLIENTID;
var clientSecret =  process.env.MCLOUD_SECRET;

///////////////////
// SOAP - fuelsdk-node - Mcloud
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
mcloudTools.IET_Client = new ET_Client(clientId,clientSecret);

/**
 * CREATE TRIGGERED SEND - SOAP
 */
mcloudTools.postTriggeredSend = function(options, app) {

    var options = {
        props: {
            "Name" : "SDKTriggeredSend"
            ,"Description" : "SDK Created TriggeredSend"
            ,"AutoAddSubscribers" : true
            ,"Email": {"ID" : 8275974}
            ,"List": {"ID" : 39333082}
            ,"SendClassification": {"CustomerKey" : "371"} // Default Transactional
        }
    };

    var triggeredSend = this.IET_Client.triggeredSend(options);

    return new BPromise(function(fulfill, reject) {

        return triggeredSend.post(function(err,response) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                fulfill(response);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

As for the "SendClassification - CustomerKey"...

mc.exacttarget.com - go to Email Studio, then top menu "Admin"
Left sidebar, you should see "Send management ≥ Send Classifications"

I use "Default Transactional" = 371, that worked for me.